# set scroll left to start at zero on refresh not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why wont this work in IE, if I move the scroll bar to the middle then Refresh it will not reset to zero, instead it stays where is was last left?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scrollLeft(0);


});
```

Thanks

Comment: `$(document).ready(...`, not `$(document.ready(...`

Comment: thanks but that was a typo and not the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script should work as you need

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $(window).bind("scroll", ScrollOnLoad);
    // IE fix, remove scroll handler after 150ms
    setTimeout(UnbindScroll, 150); 
});

function ScrollOnLoad() {
    UnbindScroll();
    $(window).scrollLeft(0);
}

function UnbindScroll() {
    $(window).unbind("scroll", ScrollOnLoad);
}
```

As you find out, the behaviour of IE is different. It triggers `scroll` event even after `document.ready`. This script will hook up on this event and `scrollLeft(0)` after refresh (in all browsers).

The complicated part is, how to solve new comers, when user visits the page for a first time. Then Internet Explorer does not fire `scroll` event. And our handler is still in play (and would scroll left when user first time scroll right).

We have to unbind `scrollLeft` manually. That's why after 150ms is the handler unbounded anyway.

Comment: This is pretty crazy - is there some documentation that explains why/what this happens?? I am seeing this sort of issue in Chrome as well.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('body, html').scrollLeft(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body, html').scrollLeft(0);
});
```